# Binomial Coefficient Conjecture

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

If I have a statement $P_n$ that states that for all $k = 1, 2, .... , n-1$ the binomial coefficient is a multiple of $n$. A natural question is: "For what values of $n$ is $P_n$ true?

I don't really understand how to go about trying to write a conjecture for the answer to the question. Can someone help me?

Comment: Have you tried doing some test cases?

Comment: What do you mean by test cases?

Comment: Hint: take a look at [Pascal's triangle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal%27s_triangle). Maybe some pattern jumps to the eye.

Comment: Note that ${{n} \choose {k}} / n = \frac{(n-1)!}{(n-k)!k!} = {{n-1} \choose {k-1}} / k$. If $k$ and $n$ are coprime, then ${{n} \choose {k}} / n$ must be an integer as when you multiply it by $k$ you get an integer. This explains the pattern you see in Pascal's triangle when $n$ is prime.

Comment: Can you explain this conclusion?

Comment: @Dylan Test cases means determining the truth value of $P_2, P_3, P_4, P_5$, etc. and seeing if there is a pattern among the small values of $n$ for which $P_n$ is true.